# Why does Wolfram|Alpha make a mistake here?

Tags: calculus, limits, wolfram-alpha

We want to evaluate $$\lim_{x \to -8}\frac{\sqrt{1-x}-3}{2+\sqrt[3]{x}}.$$The solving process can be written as follows:\begin{align*}\lim_{x \to -8}\frac{\sqrt{1-x}-3}{2+\sqrt[3]{x}}&=\lim_{x \to -8}\left[\frac{(\sqrt{1-x}-3)(\sqrt{1-x}+3)}{(2+\sqrt[3]{x})(4-2\sqrt[3]{x}+\sqrt[3]{x^2})}\cdot \frac{4-2\sqrt[3]{x}+\sqrt[3]{x^2}}{\sqrt{1-x}+3}\right]\\&=\lim_{x \to -8}\left[\frac{-(x+8)}{x+8}\cdot \frac{4-2\sqrt[3]{x}+\sqrt[3]{x^2}}{\sqrt{1-x}+3}\right]\\&=-\lim_{x \to -8} \frac{4-2\sqrt[3]{x}+\sqrt[3]{x^2}}{\sqrt{1-x}+3}\\&=-2.\end{align*}

But when I input [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim%5Cfrac%7B%5Csqrt%7B1-x%7D-3%7D%7B2%2B%5Csqrt%5B3%5D%7Bx%7D%7D%20as%20x%20to%20-8)

```
lim\frac{\sqrt{1-x}-3}{2+\sqrt[3]{x}} as x to -8
```

into Wolfram|Alpha, it gives the limit $0$.

Why is Wolfram|Alpha making a mistake here?

Comment: You should better find your mistake.

Comment: can you point out my fault?

Comment: I do not now what you are doing. But the numerator is $0$ and the denomiator is $\ne 0$ for $x=-8$.

Comment: @metamorphy: Typo corrected, you cannot use LH because the denomiator is $\ne 0$ when using the principal cube-root.

Comment: @gammatester $2+\sqrt[3]{-8}=2+(-2)=0.$

Comment: No, the principle cube root is $1 +i\sqrt{3} \ne 0$

Comment: @gammatester We only research the real number domain, not complex analysis.

Comment: But you asked about Wolfram Alpha, and there is lot of information in the answer for your WA query. So you had better asked, why does WA use complex numbers and not what is WA's mistake.

Comment: It is easy to make WA get the Wrong Answer for limitless limit questions, even when it interprets the question correctly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cubic root of negative numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/25528/cubic-root-of-negative-numbers)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

WolframAlpha understands the expression $\sqrt[3]{x}$ for negative x in a different way than you expect.

Try [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim%5Cfrac%7B%5Csqrt%7B1-x%7D-3%7D%7B2%2Bsurd(x,3)%7D%20as%20x%20to%20-8): `lim\frac{\sqrt{1-x}-3}{2+surd(x,3)} as x to -8`

Comment: you mean that WA thinks \sqrt[3]{x} no longer to be the cubic root for $x$ if $x<0$?

Comment: @mengdie1982: There is no such thing as **the** cubic root, there are three complex roots.

Comment: I grasp you. Thanks!

Comment: WA gives _a_ cube root in the complex domain.  But it will not be the _real_ cube root.  The problem is not well stated, really, unless you are told whether to use the real cube root or the principal value cube root in the complex domain, which are different things when the argument is negative.

Comment: You should include relevant details in this post, not just a link. Also, it would be beneficial to provide an explanation of the difference here.

Answer (score 14):

If you take the complex roots of $\sqrt[3]{x}$ you get $0$ as the limit, because the denominator is different from zero in this case.

So, Wolfram|Alpha did not make a mistake but just uses a different root of $\sqrt[3]{x}$.

For the real root you get $-2$:

- $t^3 = -x \Rightarrow \lim_{x \to -8}\frac{\sqrt{1-x}-3}{2+\sqrt[3]{x}} = \lim_{t \to 2}\frac{\sqrt{1+t^3}-3}{2-t} = -f'(2) \mbox{ for } f(t) = \sqrt{1+t^3}$

$$f'(t) = \frac{3t^2}{2\sqrt{1+t^3}}\Rightarrow \lim_{x \to -8}\frac{\sqrt{1-x}-3}{2+\sqrt[3]{x}} = - f'(2) = -2$$

Comment: Can you do the same for the other two, imaginary cube roots?

Comment: @Mitch: I am not quite sure what you mean. But, moving along a complex branch would mean:
$$\frac{\sqrt{1-x}-3}{2+\sqrt[3]{|x|}\sqrt[3]{-1}} =  \frac{\sqrt{1-x}-3}{2+\frac{\sqrt[3]{|x|}}{2}(1\pm i\sqrt{3})} 
 \stackrel{x\in \mathbb{R}, x\to -8}{\longrightarrow} \frac{0}{3 \pm i\sqrt{3}} = 0$$

Answer (score 3):

In Mathematica 11.3 I get

```
In[1]:= Limit[(Sqrt[1 - x] - 3)/(2 + CubeRoot[x]), x -> -8]
Out[1]= -2
```

Mathematica Documentation says `CubeRoot[x]` gives the real-valued cube root of $x$.

Even

```
In[4]:= -8^(1/3)
Out[4]= -2
```

Mathematica gives me the correct answers